# Device Motion API on android should work

Tags: javascript, android, html, accelerometer

For some reason, when using a Galaxy S3, I'm able to use the example demo from HTML5Rocks about Device Motion and get acceleration values from the phone's hardware.

Demo: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/devicemotionsample.html

But I can't seem to get the code working on my own website.  It should just be:

```
if((window.DeviceMotionEvent)||('listenForDeviceMovement'in window))    
{window.addEventListener('devicemotion',deviceMotionHandler3,false);

function deviceMotionHandler3(eventData){var     
acceleration=eventData.accelerationIncludingGravity;
```

...

Any ideas why this code would work for the website above, but not when I copy it into a blank html page?

Comment: I tested the demo with Chrome on S3 but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the device you're testing on supports detecting device motion?

Are you accessing the web page from a mobile device browser?

When I click on the link you provide from my PC I'm told that the device doesn't support the device motion event.